# How to color #define and #include preprocessors in c-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to change the default font face for preprocessor directives `#define` and `#include` without using the `font-lock-preprocessor-face`.
Instead I want to use the `font-lock-add-keywords` method and regular expressions.
I also want this to apply to assembly and C modes only.

Comment: **Duplicative**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981738/face-font-in-c-mode-when-adding-new-keyword

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't go to these measures if all you want to
do is to redefine `font-lock-preprocessor-face` for `c-mode`.
The reason is that font-lock already uses regex and it's
already slow. And now you would parse the exact same source
the second time with the exact same regex.

I used to use some custom regexes to fontify C++, but switched it off
after a year because it was slowing me down.

You can check how slow it is by opening a 50k source
and using <kbd>C-v</kbd> a bunch of times.
Now try again with `find-file-literally` - and it's fine.

Do this instead:

```
(make-face 'c-preprocessor-face)
(set-face-background 'c-preprocessor-face "blue")
(set-face-foreground 'c-preprocessor-face "yellow")
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 
                  'font-lock-comment-face)
                 'c-preprocessor-face)))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
      (lambda()
            (set (make-local-variable 
                  'c-preprocessor-face-name)
                 'c-preprocessor-face)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response abo-abo.
My main request here is to make preprocessors "#if #else #ifndef ...etc" in black and the preorpocessros "#include and #define" in blue.
For that I need to use regex. But that is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at my `comment` and `answer` to your previous question, which was essentially the same question as this current thread?

[face font in c-mode when adding new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981738/face-font-in-c-mode-when-adding-new-keyword)

Comment: Hi Lawlist....
I appreciate your followup.
My main request here is to make preprocessors "#if #else #ifndef ...etc" in black and the preorpocessros "#include and #define" in blue.
For that I need to use regex. But that is not working for me.
I could not find a working solution in what you proposed.